# How to check whether user has enabled/checked autofill credential provider extension or not from phone settings in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have implemented `AutoFill Credential Provider Extension` in iOS. 
Everything is working fine but I am having one issue, not exactly an issue but I am unable to achieve the below functionality.

I want to get `Autofill` extension state every time when user open a specific `viewController` of my application.
 So that I am able check whether it's enabled from settings or not.

If it is not enabled I will navigate user to phone settings otherwise user can use the app.

Answer (score 2):

As documented we need to use `ASCredentialIdentityStore` state for that purpose:

[image: demo]

so you can add somewhere the following wrapped async call and use it to validate of extension is enabled:

```
- (void)checkExtesionEnabledWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL))completion {
    ASCredentialIdentityStore *store = [ASCredentialIdentityStore sharedStore];
    [store getCredentialIdentityStoreStateWithCompletion:^(ASCredentialIdentityStoreState * _Nonnull state) {
        completion(state.isEnabled);
    }];
}
```